# In R, stringr:str_replace_all disobeying 'ignore_case = TRUE'

Tags: r, regex, str-replace, stringr

Is this a bug in `str_replace_all` or am I really misunderstanding something?

```
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("tidyverse")
# [1] ‘1.2.1’
R.version.string
# [1] "R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)"

fruits <- c("one apple", "two pears", "three bananas")
```

This works as expected:

```
fruits %>%
  str_replace_all(c("on\\w+" = "1", "two" = "2", "three" = "3"))
# [1] "1 apple"   "2 pears"   "3 bananas"
```

And so does this:

```
fruits %>% 
  str_replace_all(c(regex("on\\w+", ignore_case = TRUE), "two", "three"),
                  c("1", "2", "3"))
# [1] "1 apple"   "2 pears"   "3 bananas"
```

But when I try to make it case-independent, it doesn't use the `ignore_case`:

```
fruits %>% 
  str_replace_all(c(regex("ON\\w+", ignore_case = TRUE), "two", "three"),
                  c("1", "2", "3"))
# [1] "one apple" "2 pears"   "3 bananas"
```

The problem seems to be with `str_replace_all` rather than `regex`

```
fruits %>% 
  str_detect(regex("ON\\w+", ignore_case = TRUE))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

For my purposes, I've got a workaround, but -- any insights?

Comment: Probably a [Coercion](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#testing-and-coercion) issue, see the difference between `c(regex("ON\\w+", ignore_case = TRUE), "two", "three")` and `regex(c("ON\\w+", "two", "three"), ignore_case = TRUE)`.

Comment: Aha!  I didn't even notice that I was trying to mix types inside a vector.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `(?i)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
fruits %>% 
   str_replace_all(c("(?i)ON\\w+", "two", "three"),  as.character(1:3))
#[1] "1 apple"   "2 pears"   "3 bananas"
```

Or wrap everything inside `regex`

```
fruits %>% 
  str_replace_all(regex(c("ON\\w+", "two", "three"), 
            ignore_case = TRUE), c('1', '2', '3'))
 #[1] "1 apple"   "2 pears"   "3 bananas"
```